# How to scrape data dynamically with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm learning how to **scrape** data from websites using BeautifulSoup and Trying to scrape Movies link and some data about it from YTS website. But I'm stuck in it. I write a script to scrape movies type for two types. But some movies have two or more types of movies qualities in the Tech Specs area. To select i have to write code for every movie type. But how to create a for or while loop to scrape all data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

m_r = requests.get('https://yts.mx/movies/suicide-squad-2016')
m_page = BeautifulSoup(m_r.content, 'html.parser')

#------------------ Name, Date, Category ----------------
m_det = m_page.find_all('div', class_='hidden-xs')

m_detail = m_det[4]
m_name = m_detail.contents[1].string
m_date = m_detail.contents[3].string
m_category = m_detail.contents[5].string
print(m_name)
print(m_date)
print(m_category)

#------------------ Download Links ----------------
m_li = m_page.find_all('p', {'class':'hidden-xs hidden-sm'})
m_link = m_li[0]
m_link_720 = m_link.contents[3].get('href')
print(m_link_720)
m_link_1080 = m_link.contents[5].get('href')
print(m_link_1080)

#-------------------- File Size & Language -------------------------
tech_spec = m_page.find_all('div', class_='row')
s_size = tech_spec[6].contents[1].contents[1]
#-----------Convert file size to MB-----------
if 'MB' in s_size:
    s_size = s_size.replace('MB', '').strip()
    print(s_size)
elif 'GB' in s_size:
    s_size = float(s_size.replace('GB', '').strip())
    s_size = s_size * 1024
    print(s_size)
#--------- Big file Languge-----------
s_lan = tech_spec[6].contents[5].contents[2].strip()
print(s_lan)

b_size = tech_spec[8].contents[1].contents[1]
#-----------Convert file size to MB-----------
if 'MB' in b_size:
    b_size = b_size.replace('MB', '').strip()
    print(b_size)
elif 'GB' in b_size:
    b_size = float(b_size.replace('GB', '').strip())
    b_size = b_size * 1024
    print(b_size)
#--------- Big file Languge-----------
b_lan = tech_spec[8].contents[5].contents[2].strip()
print(b_lan)
```

Comment: How does the webpage look like ? Can you include the html code or website link for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

This script will get all information for each movie quality:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://yts.mx/movies/suicide-squad-2016'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for tech_quality, tech_info in zip(soup.select('.tech-quality'), soup.select('.tech-spec-info')):
    print('Tech Quality:', tech_quality.get_text(strip=True))
    file_size, resolution, language, rating = [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for td in tech_info.select('div.row:nth-of-type(1) > div')]
    subtitles, fps, runtime, peers_seeds = [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for td in tech_info.select('div.row:nth-of-type(2) > div')]
    print('File size:', file_size)
    print('Resolution:', resolution)
    print('Language:', language)
    print('Rating:', rating)
    print('Subtitles:', tech_info.select_one('div.row:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(1)').a['href'] if subtitles else '-')
    print('FPS:', fps)
    print('Runtime:', runtime)
    print('Peers/Seeds:', peers_seeds)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Tech Quality: 3D.BLU
File size: 1.88 GB
Resolution: 1920*800
Language: English 2.0
Rating: PG - 13
Subtitles: -
FPS: 23.976 fps
Runtime: 2 hr 3 min
Peers/Seeds: P/S 8 / 35
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tech Quality: 720p.BLU
File size: 999.95 MB
Resolution: 1280*720
Language: English 2.0
Rating: PG - 13
Subtitles: -
FPS: 23.976 fps
Runtime: 2 hr 3 min
Peers/Seeds: P/S 61 / 534
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tech Quality: 1080p.BLU
File size: 2.06 GB
Resolution: 1920*1080
Language: English 2.0
Rating: PG - 13
Subtitles: -
FPS: 23.976 fps
Runtime: 2 hr 3 min
Peers/Seeds: P/S 80 / 640
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tech Quality: 2160p.BLU
File size: 5.82 GB
Resolution: 3840*1600
Language: English 5.1
Rating: PG - 13
Subtitles: -
FPS: 23.976 fps
Runtime: 2 hr 2 min
Peers/Seeds: P/S 49 / 110
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```